# SML how to get while on char list to return int?

Tags: sml

I'm having a bit difficulty figuring out, how to get each of the processed chars back to an int value.

The function should work like: val caesar = fn :  int * int -> int

So if k = 2466 and n = 2, then the output should be 4688

Hope the code isn't too weird (I'm a SML newbie).

```
 (* Load Libs *)
    load "Int";
    load "Real";
    load "String";
    load "Char";
    load "List";


    fun caesar (k, n) =
      let
        fun k_string (i) = Int.toString(i)
        fun item_k_char (x, y) = Char.ord (List.nth (x, y))

        val val_k_string = k_string(k)
        val k_explode = String.explode(val_k_string)
        val counter = ref 0
        val counter_end = (String.size(val_k_string) - 1)

      in 
        while (!counter >= counter_end) do (
          item_k_char(k_explode, !counter) + n;
          counter := !counter + 1
        )
      end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A while loop isn't the best tool here. Instead you can use `map` which executes a given function for each item in a given list and returns a new list containing the result of each call to the function.

In other words: `map (fn c => (Char.ord c) + 2) [#"2", #"4", #"6", #"6"]` will return `[52,54,56,56]`. You can the convert this back to char and use `String.implode` to get the string "4688".

You probably also want to add some logic so that the numbers "wrap around", i.e. `caesar (7,7)` becomes `4`.

So all in all your code becomes:

```
fun caesar (k, n) =
  let
    val val_k_string = Int.toString k
    val k_explode = String.explode val_k_string
    val ints = map (fn c => (Char.ord c) + n) k_explode
    val wrappedAroundInts = map (fn i => (i - 48) mod 10 + 48) ints
    val chars = map Char.chr wrappedAroundInts
    val string = String.implode chars
  in
    Option.valOf (Int.fromString string)
  end
```

Comment: Wooh thx :) Could you explain the wrappedAroundInts value function, I'm not 100% sure I understand it.  Another thing, I need to add an exception for a variant of fun caesar, where I check if k is = 8. Can it be done like this? caesar2(k, n : int) = if Option.valOf (Int.fromString (String.size (Int.toString (k)))) != 8 then
 raise Fail "k must be 8 characters long"

Comment: @TBK: The wrapping works like this: `Char.ord` returns an int between 48 (ASCII value of `#"0"`) and 57 (ASCII value of `#"9"`). After adding `n` the value may be larger than 57 (and thus no longer represent a digit). To get around that, we subtract 48 and take the result modulo 10. Now we have a number between 0 and 9. By adding 48 again we get a number between 48 and 57 again and thus a valid digit.

Comment: @TBK: If you want to check whether `k` is 8, you can just do `if k = 8 then`. If you want to check whether `k` has 8 digits, you can do `if String.size (Int.toString k) = 8`. If you want to check whether `k` does not have 8 digits, you can use `if String.size (Int.toString k) = 8`. There is no need to use `fromString` as `size` returns an integer.

Comment: Super, I really appreciate it :D

Comment: @TBK: Ehrm, in my last comment I meant to say "If you want to check whether k does not have 8 digits, you can use `if String.size (Int.toString k) <> 8`" (`<>` instead of `=`). And you're welcome.

Comment: Yup, saw that and looked up the Int lib where I also figured out it must be <>. Thanks again :)